# orderGraphviz - fixed subgraphs

Tags: graphviz, dot

I like to create a 3 column graph like this:

[image]

Code:

```
digraph g {
rankdir="LR";
node[shape = circle, fontsize=14];
fontsize=18;
labeljust="l";

{ rank=same;
}

edge[style=invis, fontsize=12];
subgraph clusterA {
    a->b;
    label="A";
}
subgraph clusterC {
  e->f->g;
    label="C";
}

subgraph clusterB {
 c->d;
label="B";
}

}
```

I want to create a graph with the subgraphs A,C,B ordering. How can I add relations to this graph (ex. c->f; and b->g;) without the remaining the order of A--C--B?

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding the edges which are not supposed to influence the layout with **`constraint=false`**. After the last cluster, insert something like:

```
edge[constraint=false, style=solid];
c->f;
b->g;
```

If the clusters get reordered anyway, you may add **invisible edges** (make sure that `constraint=true`) to enforce the layout:

```
c -> e [constraint=true, style=invis];
e -> a [constraint=true, style=invis];
```