# Re-ordering 2nd tier of nodes in graphviz dot notation

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to re-order my 2nd tier so they are in numbered order.  CHeck out my graphviz dot notation here->

```
graph G {
node [shape=none,image="switch.png"];
graph [hostidtype="hostname", version="1:0", date="07/09/2014"];
splines=line;
rank=LR;
nodesep=1;
ranksep=1;
"tier2_0":"swp3" -- "tier1_0":"swp3" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=sw headport=nw
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];  
"tier2_0":"swp4" -- "tier1_2":"swp4" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=se headport=nw
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];  
"tier2_1":"swp3" -- "tier1_1":"swp3" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=sw headport=ne
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];  
"tier2_1":"swp4" -- "tier1_3":"swp4" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=se headport=ne
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];  
"tier2_2":"swp4" -- "tier1_0":"swp4" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=sw headport=ne
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];  
"tier2_2":"swp3" -- "tier1_2":"swp3" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=se headport=ne
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
]; 
"tier2_3":"swp4" -- "tier1_1":"swp4" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=sw headport=nw
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];  
"tier2_3":"swp3" -- "tier1_3":"swp3" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=se headport=nw
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];  
"tier1_0":"swp1" -- "leaf0":"swp1" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=sw headport=nw
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];
"tier1_1":"swp2" -- "leaf0":"swp2" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=sw headport=ne
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
];
"tier1_0":"swp2" -- "leaf1":"swp2" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=se headport=nw
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
];
"tier1_1":"swp1" -- "leaf1":"swp1" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=se headport=ne
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
];
"tier1_2":"swp1" -- "leaf2":"swp1" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=sw headport=nw
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp1</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp3</font></td></tr></table>>
];
"tier1_3":"swp2" -- "leaf2":"swp2" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=sw headport=ne
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
];
"tier1_2":"swp2" -- "leaf3":"swp2" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=se headport=nw
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
];
"tier1_3":"swp1" -- "leaf3":"swp1" [
fontsize = 10
tailport=se headport=ne
taillabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
headlabel =<<table border="0" cellborder="0" bgcolor="#a8cc8b"><tr><td align="center"><font color="black" face="arial">swp2</font></td></tr></table>>
];
```

}

This is what the output looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKzQP.png

Notice how the 2nd tier and 1st tier are out of order, it liked re-ordered it but I think it will make more sense to have it in order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some useful techniques to control the layout of nodes include:

- [invisible edges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374543/63733)
- [rank constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322033/63733)
- edges with [`constraint=false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14273676/63733)
- [invisible nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675212/63733)

Most useful when [combined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578764/63733).