# Crown graph in graphviz - how to preserve order correctly?

Tags: graphviz

I've written the following graphviz code to draw a crown graph on 8 nodes:

```
graph G {
  u1 [label=<<I>u<SUB>1</SUB></I>>]
  v1 [label=<<I>v<SUB>1</SUB></I>>]
  u2 [label=<<I>u<SUB>2</SUB></I>>]
  v2 [label=<<I>v<SUB>2</SUB></I>>]
  u3 [label=<<I>u<SUB>3</SUB></I>>]
  v3 [label=<<I>v<SUB>3</SUB></I>>]
  u4 [label=<<I>u<SUB>4</SUB></I>>]
  v4 [label=<<I>v<SUB>4</SUB></I>>]
  u1 -- v2 
  u1 -- v3 
  u1 -- v4
  u2 -- v1
  u2 -- v3
  u2 -- v4
  u3 -- v1
  u3 -- v2
  u3 -- v4
  u4 -- v1
  u4 -- v2
  u4 -- v3
}
```

The result when compiled with `dot` is good, but not quite what I want - I need the order of the top 'layer' of nodes to be `u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4`, and the bottom layer to be `v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4`, so that it can look like a crown graph. However, I'm not sure how to tell `dot` to do this. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some useful techniques to control the layout of nodes include:

- [invisible edges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374543/63733)
- [rank constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322033/63733)
- edges with [`constraint=false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14273676/63733)
- [invisible nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675212/63733)

Most useful when [combined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578764/63733).

In this particular case, you may apply **`constraint=false`** on your edges in order to not have them influence the layout, and add **invisible edges** to position the nodes.

Insert the following bit between your node declarations and the edge list (after line 9):

```
  edge[style=invis]
  u1 -- v1
  u2 -- v2
  u3 -- v3
  u4 -- v4
  edge[style=visible, constraint=false]
```